# I get an error when I want to upload multiple images

Tags: node.js, multer

This is the data that I send from postman

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SP2Lf.png)

It is the code

```
const multer = require("multer");

// Multer configuration
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    // Specify the destination directory to save the uploaded files
    cb(null, "public/imgs");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    // Generate a unique filename for each uploaded file
    const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + "-" + Math.random();
    cb(null, file.fieldname + "-" + uniqueSuffix);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

exports.uploadSingleImage = upload.single("imageCover");
exports.uploadMultipleImages = upload.array("images", 3);
```